# Sed: remove digits if not followed with a dot . and the return line if the line not ends with dot .?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I want to remove initial digits that are not followed by a dot (`.`) 
and remove newlines (`\n`) if the line does not end with dot (`.`).

This is the sample text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac tellus nunc. Phasellus 
pellentesque, suscipit ac nunc. Etiam lobortis, massa ac aliquam auctor, augue nisl 
53sagittis urna, at dapibus tellus erat ullamcorper ligula. 
Praesent orci dui, pulvinar id convallis a, faucibus non mauris.

2.Cras vitae tortor purus
5. ut tincidunt mauris. Sed at velit nisl.
8. Donec eu mauris tortor, interdum condimentum erat

65Donec tellus augue, tempus sed facilisis sed, fringilla quis leo. Mauris vulputate, leo
ac facilisis vulputate, enim orci interdum augue, in blandit quam turpis
quis dui. Morbi dictum luctus velit nec faucibus.
```

The output I want:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac tellus nunc. Phasellus pellentesque, suscipit ac nunc. Etiam lobortis, massa ac aliquam auctor, augue nisl sagittis urna, at dapibus tellus erat ullamcorper ligula. 
Praesent orci dui, pulvinar id convallis a, faucibus non mauris.

2.Cras vitae tortor purus
5. ut tincidunt mauris. Sed at velit nisl.
8. Donec eu mauris tortor, interdum condimentum erat

Donec tellus augue, tempus sed facilisis sed, fringilla quis leo. Mauris vulputate, leo ac facilisis vulputate, enim orci interdum augue, in blandit quam turpis quis dui. Morbi dictum luctus velit nec faucibus.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not match your description. In your sample output (and contrary to your description), `\n` is not removed if:

- the line is empty
- the line starts with digits + dot (e.g. `2.Cras vitae tortor purus`)
- the line ends with dot + spaces (e.g. `... ligula. \n`)

This perl code implements these requirements:

```
perl -pe 'next if /^\d+\./; s/^\d+//; chomp if /\S/ && !/\.\s*$/'
```

I.e.

- do nothing if the line starts with digits + dot, otherwise:
- remove leading digits
- remove trailing newline if the line contains at least one non-whitespace character and does not end with dot + optional whitespace

Answer (score 1):

The (pretty horrible) `sed` you probably want is:

```
sed -re ':a;N;$!ba;s/[[:digit:]]+([^.])/\1/g;s/([^.])\n/\1/g' file.txt
```

(Treating the whole file as a stream, replace one or more digits followed by 'not-a-dot' with the 'not-a-dot', then replace all 'not-a-dot' followed by newline with 'not-a-dot' match.

However while it matches your request, it outputs subtly different results to what you asked for, due to the multiple blank lines, and lack of dots on the end of some list items - so you may need to rethink your approach:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac tellus nunc. Phasellus pellentesque, suscipit ac nunc. Etiam lobortis, massa ac aliquam auctor, augue nisl sagittis urna, at dapibus tellus erat ullamcorper ligula. Praesent orci dui, pulvinar id convallis a, faucibus non mauris.
2.Cras vitae tortor purus5. ut tincidunt mauris. Sed at velit nisl.
8. Donec eu mauris tortor, interdum condimentum erat
Donec tellus augue, tempus sed facilisis sed, fringilla quis leo. Mauris vulputate, leoac facilisis vulputate, enim orci interdum augue, in blandit quam turpisquis dui. Morbi dictum luctus velit nec faucibus.
```